# Excluding category from [recent_products] shortcode in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We have a POS system running on woocommerce which we use for instore purchases. This means we have a category for items that we do not sell online. I have a plugin which succesfully hides these categories and associated products from the front end but this does not affect the items display when we use the [recent_products] shortcode for some reason.

I've attempted to butcher the shortcode to hide this specific category but the items still show:

```
[recent_products per_page="4" order="desc" cat_operator="NOT IN" category="instore"]
```

Is this even possible using the recent product's shortcode? Am I maybe missing something or is there another way I can display new products and exclude the category 'instore' - **instore** is the category slug, by the way, the full category name is **Instore only**

[image: Category Slug]

This has been troubling me for a while now.

Any suggestions will be most welcome.

Best Regards
Donna

Comment: I have tested your code and it works without any problems! are you sure the slug is correct? maybe a caching issue? what also seems to work is replacing `cat_operator="NOT IN"` with `operator="NOT IN"`

Comment: @7uc1f3r I agree with you. On paper, this should be working. I'm suspecting a different taxonomy maybe? maybe product tags or any custom ones? also, in `parse_attributes` located in class-wc-shortcode-products.php we can see that the new version works with `cat_operator` and `operator` is replaced with 'cat_operator' in `parse_legacy_attributes`. so `cat_operator` shoud do the job (depending on WC version).

Comment: @Dtorr1981 are sure that 'instore' is a woocomerce "product_cat" term and not a tag?

Comment: @Sadoo Is the term the same as the slug? I've updated my question with a screenshot of the categories showing the slug. I have turned off Cloudflare and also purged the site cache but a particular product 'Bows' is still showing on the frontend. IN addition, the site uses WP Bakery - could this be causing a conflict?

Comment: Well, page builders do sometimes have their own queries. can you send me some access info or something that I can dive deep and see what is happening under the hood?

Comment: @Sadoo The website is dupontdancewear dot com - one of the offending products in the first one in the recent products called 'Bows',

Comment: I don't see the bows. Looks like it is working and if youre still seeing them, could be the caching thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you want to hide it from shortcodes, why dont we give this quy a try:

```
function dont_show_instore_products( $args, $atts ) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = [
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => ['instore'],
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            ];
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'dont_show_instore_products', 10, 2 );
```

just add this to your theme's `functions.php` right before the ending `?>` or if the `functions.php` doesnt have `?>` just add it after the last line and lets see if it does what it should do.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not do as intended either - this site was inherited by me and is always a bit problematic.

Comment: Just an update, I have used an incognito window and this now seems to work - maybe the issue was caused by me being logged in hence could still see the excluded products?

Comment: I think this could be an issue with cache. Most caching plugins don't cache the website for logged-in users.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with the `recent_products` shortcode alone... would need hook into the `woocommerce_shortcode_products_query` filter with some PHP code.  Though I think you can achieve what you want with the `products` shortcode like this:

```
[products limit="4" orderby="id" order="DESC" visibility="visible" cat_operator="NOT IN" category="instore"]
```

More examples here: https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#scenario-4-newest-products

Comment: I've used the resource link to test and it still doesn't exclude the instore category. It's proving to be a bit more difficult than I think it should be. If you have any additional suggestions I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: Just to add to what @mikerojas said for developers who might need it in future: if you wanna pass a new attribute to `woocommerce_shortcode_products_query` that wasn't supported by default, you need to add it to supported attributes for this shortcode by filtering `shortcode_atts_recent_products`.